# Which technologies are most relevant for mobile broadband ISP bonding?

Tags: tunnel, gre, vyos

If I have edge router and core router (kind of Hub) and few ISP lines between them what are the most relevant technologies to be used for mobile broadband bonding?
Expected result is:

- if one of ISP lines fail, VPN connections should keep running;
- if all ISP lines work, bandwidth is increased;
- possibility to collect metrics for each ISP line;

Please refer to diagram.

[image: network diagram]

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you mean by relevant technologies.  Bonding different ISPs rarely works in practice because of out of order packets.  The "technology" you use will be mostly determined by what your ISP will support.  But questions about consumer-grade equipment are off topic here.  You can try asking this question on [sf].

Answer (score 1):

*Bonding* is a term normally used for aggregating links on the link layer - that generally isn't possible with different ISPs or without explicit ISP support.

What you are looking for is a load balancer or a load-balancing feature on a router/firewall. A VyOS router should already be capable of that.

There's no single technology that saves you from configuring the load balancing. You can balance by protocol, source, current bandwidth, ...

You cannot use a simple round-robin packet scheme: that breaks with NAT for IPv4 or general routing for IPv6.